# using more dataframes in ggplot 2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get an error when i try to use more than one dataframe in a ggplot2; Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

```
xdf <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c(18,11,16))
ydf <- data.frame(x=c(5,7), y=c(18,11))

ggplot(xdf, aes(x,y))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(ydf, aes(x,y) )
```

Is this solvable...?

Comment: data is the 2nd argument in [geoms](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html), either explicitly call `data=ydf` or supply data as 2nd argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that `ydf` is the `data` parameter:

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(x,y))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=ydf, aes(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional remarks for others who need to work with different data in `ggplot2`:

If you define `aes` globally within the function `ggplot` and you need the same aesthetics, you do not have to write them again.

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ydf)
```

If you need different aesthetics, you can set `inherit.aes = FALSE` to ignore the global aesthetics.

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=ydf, aes(y, x), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```